# Server 2008 R2 OMSA Hot Spare

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, raid, partition, diskmanagement, dell-openmanage

Using the OMSA tool in Windows Server 2008 R2 I have created a new RAID 5 array and virtual disk called `Vault`.

I have created this RAID from 6 x 1TB physical HDDs. This is how it appears in OMSA;

[image]

[image]

As you can see, the total storage capacity is 4,655GB - shouldn't it be larger as I am using 6 x 1TB HDDs? None of the disks are assigned a hot spares.

Also, I would like to dedicate one hot spare the the `Vault` virtual disk, but when I click 'Assign/Unassign Dedicated Hot Spare' the following message appears;

> Storage Management only displays those disks that can be used as a hot
>   spare. There are currently no disks that are available, large enough,
>   or of the correct type to be used as a hot spare for this virtual
>   disk.

Do I need to reconfigure the virtual disk in some way in order to assign a hot spare?

The only options I see are;

- Blink
- Unblink
- Offline

Note: there is currently no data on the virtual drive so I can safely re-create and/or reconfigure.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no data on the virtual drive simply delete it and re-create. This time when allocating hard drives, select all but one. Then at the final step you can select this as the hot spare.

Hope this helps.